# Electon-positron annihilation ratio and vacuum polarization in QCD

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

It is commonly defined the ratio

$$R(s)= \frac{\sigma(e^+e^-\longrightarrow \textrm{hadrons}; s)}{\sigma(e^+e^-\longrightarrow \mu^+\mu^-;s)}$$ where $s$ is the center-of-mass energy squared. I found in many references that $$ R(s)= \frac{1}{2i\pi} \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \left[ \Pi(s+i\varepsilon)- \Pi(s-i\varepsilon)  \right] $$ where $\Pi(q^2)$ is the vacuum polarization function. How is the proof of this made?

Comment: A belated welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. If you found this in many references, it would be helpful to include in the question some links tor citations to a few of those of references.